How do I determine the current memory being used?

Is Active Memory considered as memory that is currently being used?
I need to determine the memory being used by the switch currently for Preventive Health Checkup.
In this screenshot I can only see
Total memory
Reserved memory
Wired memory
Active memory
Inactive memory
Cache memory

You can check here what each items means:
Items That Consume Memory

Wired Memory: Always active and never swapped out.
Active Memory: Currently being used by running processes.
Inactive Memory: Used by processes but not accessed recently.
Used Memory: Total memory currently in use (includes active and inactive memory).
Buffer Memory: Used for temporary storage to help with input/output operations.
Cached Memory: Almost free and can be quickly allocated for new processes if needed.
Swap: Virtual memory that has been moved to disk to free up physical RAM.

Items That Do Not Directly Consume Memory

Total Memory: Overall memory available in the system at startup (not an active consumer, just a measure of capacity).
Reserved Memory: Memory set aside at startup, not managed by the virtual memory system (reserved but not actively consuming like other categories).
Free Memory: Memory currently available for new processes and allocations.
Available Memory: An estimate of how much memory is free and usable for new applications without needing to swap.


Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Code-blocks should be reserved for code and input/output that must be formatted fixed-width.  See How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML? and the Markdown help.  Helpful Hint:  You can click "Edit" under any question or answer to see how it was formatted.
